# Android : Trying to run in 2.3.6

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using a bit old Android mobile and Android version is 2.3.6

Which Android version should I choose in "Minimum Required SDK, Target SDK, Compile with" when creating the new Android project?

I am trying to run sample applications in my mobile phone having the version 2.3.6 from Eclipse itself.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can check the corresponding android version code

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history

For your case should be Android 2.3.3–2.3.7 Gingerbread (API level 10)

For the Minimum Required SDK, Target SDK you should put 10